# Quotient category $Coh_d/Coh_{d-1}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme, and $Coh(X)_d$ be the category of coherent sheaves of support <= d dimensional.

Why is $Coh(X)_d/Coh(X)_{d-1}$ equivalent to $\oplus_{x \in X^{(d)}} \mathcal{A}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$?

See: http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~mseverit/algkalgc.pdf page 2, 6th equation.

Comment: http://www.matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?rd2&topic=155261&start=0#p1177208

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: I haven't really understood the answer in detail, so perhaps someone else can write a better answer.